# Type Cast from class A to class B object which share the same protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

> **Cast from 'A' to unrelated type 'B' always fails**

```
protocol P {
    var name: String { get set }
    var age: Int { get set }
}

class A: P {
    var name: String

    var age: Int

    var address: String

    init(na: String, ag: Int, a: String) {
        self.name = na
        self.age = ag
        self.address = a
    }
}

class B: P {
    var name: String

    var age: Int

    var number: String

    init(na: String, ag: Int, nu: String) {
        self.name = na
        self.age = ag
        self.number = nu
    }
}

var a = A(na: "Aa", ag: 20, a: "not")
var b = B(na: "Ra", ag: 22, nu: "23232")

if let n = a as? B {
    print(n)
}
```

How can I cast the object to access the common property?

Comment: `a` is not `B`. You can't cast it to `B`. Sharing a protocol here isn't relevant. You can `as P` if you want to treat it as `P`. But it's not `B`. You don't have to cast the object at all to access its property, though.

Comment: Make one class derive from another, the first one with common properties and other an extension of that.

Comment: I think the confusion stems from your expectation that A and B are compatible types just because they have a similar structure. This is true for tuples and function types (which follow "structural typing" in Swift), but not for structs, classes, and protocol types (which follow "nominal" typing). See https://medium.com/@thejameskyle/type-systems-structural-vs-nominal-typing-explained-56511dd969f4

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast anything. Simply treat A and B as P. Assuming you're using a playground you can do something like this.

```
var a = A(na: "Aa", ag: 20, a: "not")
var b = B(na: "Ra", ag: 22, nu: "23232")

func show(_ p: P) {
    print("Name: \(p.name)")
    print("Age: \(p.age)")
}

show(a)
show(b)
```

Comment: actually I need to pass object a to method where its expecting (b: B) as the protocol is not available. So, creating the object of "b" with "a" property is the only solution here?

Comment: If your function is expecting B then you have to pass it a B. I'm not sure why you'd want to pass an A to a function expecting a B though. You aren't giving us much context as to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your object as 'P' type, like this

```
let n: P = a
```